# How to take Multi-value from one sentence using API.AI?

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

I'm new to Api.ai , i read the doc. but i didn't understand how Api.ai works better with many parameters.

I'll try to explain by an example :
I have a Management software which manages the members/actions/projects , where i can get the actions of any member at any project using the normal interface.

let's replace this with a smart bot where the chat will run as i expected below,

USER : i want to see my actions for ANY PROJECT NAME HERE 
bot : your action is XXXXXX.

OR

USER: give me all the members of the project ANY PROJECT NAME
Bot: Members are "1-2-3-4-5-...."

i think you got what i mean , if you need more i can explain more.How can i let Api.ai understands this ?

Answer (score 2):

For API.ai to 'remember' values (ie store and retrieve information such as the names of projects, actions and team members) you will need to connect API.ai to a webhook/database of your own, there isn't anyway for API.ai to do this on its own.

Once you connect API.ai to a custom webhook/database you can use the variables that API.ai will parse for you to run your query. You simply need to build the intents corresponding to the search and parameters involved

Here's how the process would flow:

1. User asks "I want to see my actions for [ANY PROJECT NAME HERE]"
2. API ai logic recognizes this as the intent 'search-action' for $project_name, you having set this up in API.ai like this

[image]

3. Your custom webhook receives JSON response from API.ai that in this case would look like this:

```js
{
  "id": "REDACTED",
  "timestamp": "2017-04-19T03:18:18.028Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "I want to see my actions for project Unicorn",
    "action": "search-action",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "project_name": "project Unicorn"
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "REDACTED",
      "webhookUsed": "false",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "intentName": "Search - Actions"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "REDACTED"
}
```

So, your webhook has logic that recognizes when `result.action` is 'search-action' is should run a database search for actions in project `result.parameters.project_name`

4. Your webhook fulfills the API.ai request, or alternatively, sends message to message platform directly (ie Facebook messenger)